# A simple inequality: $(x+y)^p>x^p+y^p?$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y>0$ and $p>1$. Is it always true that $$(x+y)^p>x^p+y^p?$$

I think it is true. But can not prove it.

Comment: Did you even try? Expand $(x+y)^p$ using the Binomial Theorem...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264156

Comment: Expanding for fractional $p$ would not yield any negative coefficients...?

Comment: How? You specified $x,y>0$.

Comment: Thanks@sdcvvc. So, it is true..?

Comment: If you can't answer this question after my comment and the links to two other questions asking the same thing, then I don't know what to say.

Comment: @iHubble How can the OP expand $(x+y)^p$ using the Binomial Theorem if $p$ is not an integer?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the comments and help. sdcvvc's answer is great and it is true.

Comment: @thanasissdr, great question. I immediately assumed $p \in \mathbb{N}$ since this letter is usually reserved for integers (e.g. $p$-adic numbers, $p$-norms, etc.)

Comment: @iHubble I think the OP should state if $p>1$ is either an integer or any real number, otherwise I don't know if the Binomial Theorem would be helpful, at least at this form of the problem.

Comment: @thanasissdr, there is a generalized version of the Binomial Theorem that holds for any exponent $r \in \mathbb{C}$. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem).

Comment: removed my answer which was indeed a comment - and here is the comment: For the case that $x,y\geq 0$ it is, otherwise you could choose $x=-y$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: @iHubble Sure, but things will get pretty complicated (infinite sum)..

Answer (score 4):

Since the inequality is homogeneous, we may assume without loss of generality that $y=1$ and $x\in(0,1]$, then prove:
$$ \forall x\in(0,1],\qquad (1+x)^p > 1+x^p.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, if we set $f(x)=(1+x)^p-x^p$, it is straightforward to check that $f'(x) = (p-1)\cdot\left((1+x)^{p-1}-x^{p-1}\right)>0$, hence $f$ is increasing on $(0,1]$. Since $f(0)=1$, $(1)$ is proved.

Comment: This is a new approach, while I found answers by timon92 and A1DHTH are essentially same as that by sdcvcc (look at the link by his/her comments). I upvoted both the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously for any $1>t>0$ and $p>1$ we have $t>t^p$ thus $$\frac{x}{x+y} > \left( \frac{x}{x+y} \right)^p \hbox{ and } \frac{y}{x+y} > \left( \frac{y}{x+y} \right)^p.$$ Summing up and multiplying by $(x+y)^p$ we get $(x+y)^p > x^p+y^p$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0 < \dfrac{x}{x+y} < 1, 0 < \dfrac{y}{x+y} < 1 \Rightarrow \left(\dfrac{x}{x+y}\right)^p < \dfrac{x}{x+y}, \left(\dfrac{y}{x+y}\right)^p < \dfrac{y}{x+y}$. Adding these inequalities, the answer follows.

Answer (score -2):

Let $x,y>0$ and $p>1$ so we must prove $(x+y)^p > x^p + y^p$. We can prove this by saying that $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p + c(x,y)$ where $c(x,y)$ are terms of $x,y$ that are combined. If $x,y>0$ then so must $c(x,y)$ because it will be the sum of products of positive numbers. Example for $c(x,y)$ $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2xy$. Thus as we know $c(x,y)>0$ we can say $(x+y)^p = x^p + y^p + c(x,y) > x^p + y^p$ and if we subtract $x^p + y^p$ from both sides we get $c(x,y)>0$ which is true.

Comment: You can't say "As we know $c(x,y) > 0$" by invoking an example with $p=2$. You're doing this backward.

Comment: This is a simplification of the binomial theorem where $c(x,y)=\sum_k ^{(n-1)} \binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}y^k$

Comment: I was giving an example of what $c(x,y)$ could be, I wasn't using my example as proof.

Comment: What about $p=\frac{23}{17}$?